# Por que usar/não usar * box-sizing?

Tags: css, css3

Já li muito a respeito de debates entre usar ou não usar a propriedade `box-sizing: border-box;` da seguinte maneira:

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box; 
}
```

Sei que ela é bem influente, especialmente na elaboração do layout, como interação entre bordas, paddings, etc.

Mas por que usar ela deste modo? Ou por que não usar? Uma vez que estará aplicando o estilo a todos os elementos.

Em alguns casos que usei, pude notar uma imensa repetição das propriedades quando a hierarquia DOM era profunda.

Se não for usado deste modo, o mais correto seria definir apenas nas propriedades que vou precisar?

Ou melhor dizer, qual a real função da propriedade `box-sizing`? E qual é, de fato, o melhor modo de usar essa função?

Comment: Eu sempre uso por padrão em todos os projetos. Particularmente acho um saco ter que calcular na mão o tamanho que a div terá de ficar só por que coloquei um border ou um padding

Comment: Pois então. Tentei começar um layout sem usar essa definição, pois a repetição dela me incomodava. Mas estou me incomodando mais com a falta dela do que com o excesso. Mesmo sem saber ao certo quais os reais prós e contras disso.

Comment: Segundo a [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)
A propriedade CSS box-sizing é utilizada para alterar a propriedade padrão da box model, usada para calcular larguras (widths) e alturas (heights) dos elementos. É possível de usar essa propriedade para emular o comportamento dos navegadores (browser) que não suportam corretamente a especificação da propriedade CSS box model.

Comment: O Foundation usa tanto no *, quanto no *:after, *:before. E eu uso assim também.

Comment: Eu entendo que o uso do * ou não dá uma discussão interessante, independente do box-sizing, pelas questões de facilidade de aplicar em tudo versus o impacto no DOM. Já o box-sizing é uma propriedade como outra qualquer, que se usa conforme é necessária. Na verdade é uma propriedade que corrige uma das maiores ***adas do w3c, no meu ver (que o IE era o [único browser a fazer o que era sensato](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Explorer_box_model_bug)).

Comment: Complementando: se for usar o *, tem uma proposta muito melhor neste artigo aqui, que muda o box do HTML todo, e herda no resto dos elementos (`inherit`): https://css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice/

Comment: @Bacco Muito bem colocado! Até o momento me parece o melhor método de se usar. O que eu achava que poderia atrapalhar, ou não ser a melhor prática, era pelo fato de repetir a propriedade de um modo, digamos, "descontrolado". Vou ver o que consigo montar em cima desse conceito!

Comment: Eu só uso quando necessário. Não aplico isso ao `*`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tem dois grandes motivos para você querer padronizar o box model nos seus documentos, ou pelo menos numa parte deles:

1. Você quer ou precisa usar o modelo "tradicional" (`border-box`, o antigo modelo que todos usavam, e que sobreviveu por mais tempo no IE), que é mais intuitivo e pode ser a única solução em determinadas situações de leiautes intrincados.
2. Você está estilizando um formulário e nada parece fazer sentido. Isso porque [elementos de formulários usam box models diferentes entre si](http://www.breck-mckye.com/blog/2014/03/form-elements-box-models-quirks-and-you/), até hoje, em diversos browsers. Inclusive certos elementos ainda são fornecidos pelo sistema operacional, e não pelo browser (os elementos "substituídos", na linguagem do CSS).

Dá pra ver que no mínimo padronizar o box model dos formulários é uma decisão sensata. Quanto a padronizar tudo – alterando `box-sizing` para o elemento `html`, [e os demais via herança com `*, *:before, *:after`](https://css-tricks.com/inheriting-box-sizing-probably-slightly-better-best-practice/), fica a seu critério. Independentemente do box model com o qual você decidir trabalhar, pode sempre surgir algum caso específico em que o outro box model seria uma mão na roda. Nesses casos você pode aplicar `box-sizing` individualmente ao que precisar.

Answer (score 6):

[Este artigo do Sergio Lopes](http://sergiolopes.org/css-box-sizing-border-box/) fala sobre o assunto e mostra como a especificação de *box-model* é confusa.

---

Você usa essa propriedade para definir que, o tamanho de um elemento deve ser calculado desde a sua borda. A forma mais simples de entender é com um snippet:

```css
.a, .b {
  border: 20px solid #000;
  background: skyblue;
  font-size: 4em;
  margin: 2px;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px
}

.b {
  box-sizing: border-box
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>sopt</div>
<div class='b'>sopt</div>
```

Note que ambos os elementos possuem 300 pixels de largura.

A altura e a largura de `.a` são calculadas considerando somente o seu conteúdo (valor padrão: `box-sizing:content-box`), bordas e *padding* não são incluídos no cálculo e se você incluir um `border: 20px solid #ccc` o tamanho da sua caixa será 200px + 40px.

Com o `border-box`, o calculo será o tamanho da caixa incluindo a borda e margem interna.

Se fosse para responder "Por que usar?", eu diria simplesmente para evitar surpresas durante o desenvolvimento.

Comment: Sim, esse conceito eu compreendi. Mas por que muitos utilizam ele aplicado ao `*` e outros já preferem aplicar diretamente no elemento que é necessário, seja através de um próprio atributo, classe complementar ou funções extras (como um @include / @extend no SASS)?

Comment: Isso é opção de quem desenvolve, não tem como responder. Chutando, talvez alguns desenvolvedores achem que aplicar uma propriedade em seletor universal seja ruim (do ponto de vista de performance). Mas [não é bem assim](http://www.paulirish.com/2012/box-sizing-border-box-ftw/).