# Como limitar o tamanho de um elemento com padding em CSS?

Tags: css, height

Eu quero criar uma página HTML com uma `<div>` que possui uma altura fixa de `450px` para guardar textos e outros elementos. Para fazer isso, eu criei uma classe com as seguintes propriedades em CSS.

```css
.minhaClasse{
    height: 450px;
    max-height: 450px;
}
```

O problema é que a propriedade `max-height` não funciona quando eu adiciono `padding` para o elemento. Em algumas páginas HTML, eu preciso adicionar um `padding-top` no elemento para descer o texto na página.

Veja o exemplo abaixo:

```css
.minhaClasse{
    height: 450px;
    max-height: 450px;
}
```

```html
<body align="center">
    <div class="minhaClasse" style="padding-top: 100px;">
        Meu texto dentro da DIV 100px abaixo <br>
        (gostaria que a div permanecesse com 450px de altura)
    </div>
</body>
```

Como podem ver, o tamanho da `<div>` ultrapassa os limite de altura do elemento. O que eu quero saber é, como posso limitar a altura do meu elemento, mesmo adicionando um `padding` a ele ?

Comment: Se tem `height: 450px;` não precisa de `max-height: 450px;`, a não ser que esteja usando algum meio de diplay diferente de `block`, o que parece improvavel.

Comment: Por que usar/não usar * box-sizing? https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/100623/por-que-usar-n%C3%A3o-usar-box-sizing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se tem `height: 450px;` não precisa de `max-height: 450px;`, a não ser que esteja usando algum meio de `diplay` diferente de `block`, o que parece improvável para o seu caso, para resolver bastaria usar `box-sizing: border-box;` ou com retrocompatibilidade:

```
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
   -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
```

A propriedade box-sizing por padrão usa o valor `content-box`, cada valor tem um comportamento do box-model, que vão se comportar de maneira diferente conforme `padding`, `border`, `margin` e o próprio conteúdo

### box-sizing: content-box

Esse é o valor padrão da propriedade, faz com que o elemento tenha a altura ajustada pelo width (largura) e height (altura) e conteudo incluidos (limitados) nas medidas, mas não "limita" o `padding`, `border` e `margin`

Por exemplo se um elemento tem `height: 300px;` e adiciona um `padding-bottom: 50px;` a altura vai ser `height: 300px;`

Se só tiver a altura e o padding for zero, mas o conteúdo passar de `300px` o elemento ainda vai ter `300px`, o conteúdo só vai "vazar para fora" do box-model, pois passou do limite.

### box-sizing: padding-box

As propriedades de largura (width), altura (height) e padding  incluem (limitam-se) ao `box-model`, mas não serão incluídos `border` ou `margin`.

### box-sizing: border-box

As propriedades de largura (width) e de altura (height) `padding` e `border` incluem (limitam-se), mas não será incluído a propriedade `margin`.

Comment: O que faz o `box-sizing` ?

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 editei a resposta.